# How to crop content that crawls outside the block?

Tags: html, css

How to crop content that crawls outside the block?
https://priscree.ru/img/b7eadd32574a32.jpg
I have a block and circles behind it, I need these circles to be cropped if their height is greater than the block height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.interesting{
    overflow:hidden
}
```

should cap of anything that flows outside of the boundry box